# Different backgrounds for every box?

Tags: css

I try to change image backgrounds for every box inside a `<td>` tag but when I try to change one of these backgrounds, I obtain the same background of ALL boxes.
But it isn't what I want. 
This is the aspect of page:
[image]

The `CSS` that I'm using for box is this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
div.myautoscroll {
    height: 80ex;
    width: auto;
    background: white;
    background-image: url(cieloprato.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 1em;
}
div.myautoscroll:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
div.myautoscroll p {
    padding-right: 16px;
}
div.myautoscroll:hover p {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
</style>
```

I tried add to each `<div>` element unique identifier or class, and get it by according selector in **CSS** but something is wrong.
I want change the 2nd background but if i try to change it, the `css` also changes my first background. You can see that background for both boxes is the same `cieloprato.jpg`. I want to insert another background for 2nd or 3rd box. 
How can modify the **CSS code**?
[This is my HTML page](http://nathan3000.altervista.org/My_Site/DataTables-1.9.2/examples/basic_init/tabella%20con%20scrollbar%20e%20pagination%20-%20ma%20da%20sistemare.html#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, background image set for all div.myautoscroll ( and you see same image ). You can (for example) during generate table for every div.myautoscroll add '#myautoscroll_1','#myautoscroll_2'... '#myautoscroll_n'. And add css code:

```
#myautoscroll_1 {
   background-image: url(image_1.jpg);
}

#myautoscroll_2 {
   background-image: url(image_2.jpg);
}

#myautoscroll_n {
   background-image: url(image_n.jpg);
}
```

Comment: mmm..but code must be so? http://pastebin.com/AAGmxPg6 Because this code give me an error, no background images appears..what position should be added to the css modified? Before <td> tag or just once?

Comment: solved, i replace `<div class="myautoscroll">` with `<div class="myautoscroll" style="background-image: url(pescatori.jpg)">`...**links**...`</div>`. the position is immediately after `<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){.....` Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, CSS allows you to select elements by their (one-based) index via the [:nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) pseudoclass, so you could do something like:

```
div.myautoscroll{ /*Generic formatting for all your boxes*/
    height: 80ex;
    width: auto;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 1em;
}
#example tr:nth-child(1) div.myautoscroll{
    /* Selects all boxes in the first row of your table,
       you can use :first-child here too */
    background-image: url(cieloprato.jpg); /* This, or any other image */ }
#example tr:nth-child(2) div.myautoscroll{
    /* Selects all boxes in the second row of your table. */
    background-image: url(some_other_image.jpg); /* The image for the second box */ }
#example tr:nth-child(3) div.myautoscroll{
    /* Same as above, just for the third row */
    background-image: url(yet_another_image.jpg); /* Third image */ }
div.myautoscroll:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
div.myautoscroll p {
    padding-right: 16px;
}
div.myautoscroll:hover p {
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```